# Vba Excel Can I change to upper case using With function?

Tags: excel, uppercase, vba

Is it possible to define upper case in With function?

I have tried a few versions, but none works:

```
With Worksheets("CONTROL SCHEDULE").Range("A7:N7")
    .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Value = UCase(.Value)
End With
```

Comment: I want range A7:N7 to be upper case letters. Was hoping this was possible to define within the "With" function so I can easily add it into several places in my code. Sounds like I am better off making a separate line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UCase` won't work on an array like that. You can use `Evaluate` though:

```
With Worksheets("CONTROL SCHEDULE").Range("A7:N7")
    .Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate("INDEX(UPPER(" & .address & "),)")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. This code has only added the text "UPPER" in cell N7. How can I change the whole row?

Comment: That code would only do that if N7 had the word "upper" in it already.

Comment: Ah, I had another code further down changing it back. THANKS :)